# Display Google Analytics Data on ASP.NET Website dashboard

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

How to display Google Analytics data on my asp.net website dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [google analytics library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3)